# Is there any way to write to the clipboard from javascript, on the android browser?

Tags: javascript, android, clipboard

Or am I going to have to write an app to do that??

Answer (score 1):

This works in IE only:

```
window.clipboardData.setData('text',text);
```

Other than that, i've heard you can use Flash to mess with the clipboard, but I'm not sure why you would want to go to those lengths.

Edit: related question: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Yep, flash/as[2/3] interop is the way.

Comment: he asked for android, and as neither IE nor Flash run on an android device normaly, thats not a good answer.

Comment: Oops, reading comprehension failure on my part. My answer is "no" to the subject and "yes" to the second question.